# How do tell if the Activity state has been destroyed and needs to be recreated

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a list activity which does the usual list activity type stuff. All of the activity setup was being done in the `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_streams);  
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mStreamListAdapter = new StreamListRowAdapter(this, R.layout.stream_list_row);  
    mStreamListView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mStreamListView.setAdapter(mStreamListAdapter);
}
```

I do not have `onStart()` and `onResume()` overrides. I can successfully navigate out of this activity based on the menu buttons pressed and then navigate back to this activity. When I navigate away from this list activity via `startActivity(newIntent)`, I do not call finish, but I do call finish in the newIntent activity, when coming back to this list activity. Everything works fine, unless either the `ListActivity` itself or one of the new Activities have been sitting in the background for a long time (i.e. I switched to another app). Long time is measured in hours. Sometimes (NOT always), when I come back to my app after this delay, the list activity does not display the list, the menu is not displayed either, just a blank screen with the activity title displayed in the ActionBar.

I realize that I need to handle coming back to the list Activity via `onResume()` (and maybe `onStart()`). But `onResume()` is always called after I navigate back to this list activity, how do I really know if the variables representing the `ListAdapter` and `ListView` have actually been destroyed by the OS and need to be recreated inside `onResume()`, I don't want to recreate them every time `onResume()` is called. Can I just check to see if they are equal to null? It's hard to test this, as this does not happen very regularly.

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: How do you handle uncaught exceptions? How about trying to remove the line `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));`? I guess, if you do, you will get an exception in your described use case, which will clarify, what is wrong with your `Activity`. You will just need to investigate logcat entries

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are missing some basic information about Android and Activity's lifecycle. First I want to mention how Android saves it's state. There are 2 important points here. When leaving an Activity it is at risk of being destroyed it calls the hook method

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("myKey1", 1);
    outState.putString("myStringKey", "hello");
}
```

When this is called, this is a chance for you to save all the data that you'd like to persist. This could be ids, strings, arraylists, and nearly any other type of data.

Now that you've saved your data, in the onCreate method of your Activity you are passed back all of these values.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                String myStr = savedInstanceState.getString("myStringKey");
                int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("myKey1", -1);
            }
            // do the rest of your setup

}
```

On the first time onCreate is called savedInstanceState is null. To answer your question: "how do I really know if the variables representing the ListAdapter and ListView have actually been destroyed by the OS" this is how you can know. If savedInstanceState is not null, your stuff has probably been destroyed. However, I will say that anytime onCreate gets called that Activity was already completely destroyed anyway.

The other thing I will mention is Android is allowed to kill your backgrounded Activity whenever it needs to reclaim some memory. When it does this, it will call the onSaveInstanceState method for you. Android does not have to restart the application at the "first" or "MAIN" screen of your application. It can start off several Activities in if that's where the user left off. I mention this because it sounds like you're having issues whenever Android decides to create your activities after it clear's it's memory. The best way to make sure your application works well when this happens is to just rotate the phone. Rotate the phone from horizontal to landscape and/or back will cause the Activity to be destroyed and recreated with onSaveInstanceState called and passed back in to the onCreate. Based upon the information you've provided this is the best I can suggest for now.

Cheers.

Comment: So, checking to see if the Activity class variables (ListView and ListAdapter) are set to null inside onResume() is not enough to determine if the corresponding objects need to be recreated? That was my most recent attempt to fix this problem and it didn't seem to make any difference. I will try your suggestion tonight to see if it solves the problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out what was going on. I have 2 activities, ActivityA and ActivityB, and an Application object. Upon the application launch, ActivityA initializes some globals that are stored in the Application object and then starts ActivityB. When my app is restarted after being in the background for a long time, the onCreate() of the Application is called and then onCreate() of ActivityB is called. ActivityB relies on the variables in the Application object that normally are initialized by the ActivityA, but ActivityA is never called this time around and the globals are not initialized. I am still not clear why the ActivityA just hangs, instead of crashing with some message stating that the variables are null, which is what onCreate() in the Application object sets them to, but regardless, when this occurs, I need to go back to ActivityA() and reinitialize everything as I normally would, when the application is launched.

I now have a boolean in the Application object that indicates whether or not ActivityA has been executed after the onCreate() of the Application object has been called. ActivityB checks this boolean flag, and if not set, then simply start ActivityA to perform the on launch type initialization. I actually have to do this check in pretty much every activity.

Comment: It is definitely a very bad and unreliable design. Activity should not initialize globals. Then, it should not store them in Application. And of course it should not do any "init" work just to start another Activity, working rather as a service. If you want to store the data, there is SharedPreferences class. If you want to do some heavy lifting, you can use Sevice, AsyncTask or even retained-instance Fragment. But never do what you have described. A simple configuration change could break the whole your App.

Comment: Not sure why you are so critical, maybe I wasn't very clear. ActivityA is a startup/logo screen. It fires off AsyncTask to initialize various caches and then starts ActivityB. The references to these caches are stored in the Application object. When the Application object is destroyed, the caches have to be re-initialized, the easiest way to do this is to go back to ActivityA. I don't understand what configuration changes you are talking about, when these do occur, ActivityB is simply restarted via onCreate() by the OS and since the Application object was not destroyed, everything is fine.

Comment: It is hard to say without a code, but by doing so you could well "leak an Activity" - create one of the common Android memory leaks.
**Configuration change** is, for example, change of the screen orientation. It causes the Activity to go through destroy and create lifecycle again. By issuing an AsyncTask and not handling configuration changes, you might encounter: memory leak (leaking the whole Activity); concurrency issue (two AsyncTasks - belonging to an undead Activity and the newly created one - competing delivering data to Application); NullPointerException at the very least; etc

Comment: Do not consider it as a criticism, but rather as the advice. After all, we're all learning here. I just post my opinion, my arguments, and my experience here.

Comment: @drew: I appreciate your feedback and am constantly learning. Bottom line is what I am doing is pretty much restarting my app when the Application object's onCreate() is called. ActivityA is the launch activity and I start it when I detect that Application object's onCreate() has been called and I am in onCreate() of ActivityN. Configuration change does not cause the onCreate() of the Application object, but onCreate() of ActivityN. The only event that can cause the onCreate() of the Application object is when OS kills it. At this point, I want to restart my app.

Comment: You should put your global initialization to Application.onCreate(). Not your Application, but Android's Application.